# Определить сертификат python

Tags: python

Всем привет.
Скачал для теста антивирус malwarebytes, выбрал рандомный файл, посмотрел его сертификат, там написано: Сертификат выдан для malwarebytes Inc. У меня вопрос, как посмотреть кому выдан сертификат и как проверить его на подлинность с помощью python? Буду очень благодарен. Мне это очень нужно. Спасибо

Comment: Если вы смотрите файл, то при чём тут ssl?

Comment: @andreymal при том, что сертификаты не только у SSL бывают:)

Comment: При том, что хоть какие-то теги прикреплять надо

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev вот и я том же, ssl не имеет никакого отношения к сертификатам файла

Comment: А, я на тег не обратил внимание

Comment: Изменил. Жду критику дальше

Comment: А вообще что-то вроде бы гуглится по запросу вроде «python pe read certificate». Насчёт проверки подлинности не знаю, но на enSO есть вроде бы пример для чтения сертификата https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53862702